# import mysql data to kubernetes pod

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Does anyone know how to import the data inside my dump.sql file to a kubernetes pod either;

Directly,same way as you dealing with docker containers:

```
docker exec -i container_name mysql -uroot --password=secret database < Dump.sql
```

Or using the data stored in an existing docker container volume and pass it to the pod .

Answer (score 28):

Just if other people are searching for this :

```
kubectl -n namespace exec -i my_sql_pod_name -- mysql -u user -ppassword < my_local_dump.sql
```

Comment: Kind of surprisingly... this works great for importing a DB from local to a random pod on a remote cluster.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question:

You can [`kubectl exec`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/) into your container in order to run commands inside it. You may need to first ensure that the container has access to the file, by perhaps storing it in a location that the cluster can access (network?) and then using wget/curl within the container to make it available. One may even open up an interactive session with `kubectl exec`.

However, the ways to do this in increasing measure of generality would be:

1. Create a [service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) that lets you access the mysql instance running on the pod from outside the cluster and connect your local mysql client to it.
2. If you are executing this initialization operation every time such a mysql pod is being started, it could be stored on a [persistent volume](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/) and you could execute the script within your pod when you start up.
3. If you have several pieces of data that you typically need to copy over when starting the pod, look at [init containers](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/production-pods/#handling-initialization) for fetching that data.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
Using ConfigMaps and then use that ConfgMap as a mount into the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder

Code

MySQL Deployment

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: mysql
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.6
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: dbpassword11
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql    
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql    
            - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d #https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql Refer Initializing a fresh instance                                            
      volumes: 
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ebs-mysql-pv-claim
        - name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
          configMap:
            name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
```

MySQL ConfigMap

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: usermanagement-dbcreation-script
data: 
  mysql_usermgmt.sql: |-
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS usermgmt;
    CREATE DATABASE usermgmt;
```

Reference:

https://github.com/stacksimplify/aws-eks-kubernetes-masterclass/blob/master/04-EKS-Storage-with-EBS-ElasticBlockStore/04-02-SC-PVC-ConfigMap-MySQL/kube-manifests/04-mysql-deployment.yml

https://github.com/stacksimplify/aws-eks-kubernetes-masterclass/blob/master/04-EKS-Storage-with-EBS-ElasticBlockStore/04-02-SC-PVC-ConfigMap-MySQL/kube-manifests/03-UserManagement-ConfigMap.yml

Comment: The problem with this approach is that data mapped to the configMap is limited to 3M. Take this example: `kubectl create configmap init-script --from-file=db.sql`  `error: failed to create configmap: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728` The challenge , especially for those of us coming from a LAMP stack background, your db backup is always going to be larger than 3M for an existing application. I'm facing the same question - When deploying an existing app, how do I get my existing database dump data into that deployed app? Preferably automatically as part of a CI / CD pipeline.