# How to pass .sql file in Kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

We want to deploy *laravel* project in k8s. For database we have a `data.sql` file. When we create docker image for this project, `data.sql` was easy to pass in volume like:

volumes:

```
  - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
```

but in k8s i'm not able to make connection between the database and .sql file 
So do let me know, how to pass .sql file in kubernetes volume?

in .sql file we have a large amount of data, when we use configmap it gives an error

```
"command terminated with exit code 137"
```

Comment: its is all explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50877213/5193536

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize mysql container when created on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681780/how-to-initialize-mysql-container-when-created-on-kubernetes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the limit of 1MB for configmaps I would initiate a sidecar that pulls this sql file in an empty dir to the main container for the DB. Naturally the git method is deprecated but this should help:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gitrepo
- https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync/blob/master/docs/ssh.md

Answer (score 0):

Use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) to store the sql file. You should mount the ConfigMap as a volume in the pod.

Comment: The ConfigMap "my-config" is invalid: []: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters

Comment: there is a limit of 1 MB for configmap object.

Comment: we need a min 1Gi space for data

Comment: for data mount persistent volume using a pvc